# Can I use a hard drive PCB from a lower-capacity model?

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I sold an old 640GB 2.5" SATA hard drive on eBay, only to accidentally pull too hard on the data cable and ripping out the data connector.

I've cancelled the eBay listing, and have been browsing for a new PCB to replace the one I broke, and came across a PCB from the same model drive, but with a **lower storage capacity**.

The drive I found has bad sectors so it's being sold cheaply (I only need the PCB, so it's exactly what I need), however the drive is a 160GB model and my own drive is 640GB.
I've verified that they ***are*** the same model drive, just with a different capacity.

Would I be able to use the PCB from the 160GB model on my 640GB model?
Would I get the full drive (590Gb-or so), or would it not work?

Comment: It's very unlikely to work because the firmware is model-specific. Even if you found the same model, it still might not work because there's sometimes device-specific calibration information in the flash.

Comment: If you do this and it works (unlikely) I would urge you to disclose the fact on your listing. I wouldn't buy it.

Comment: @Steve Please read the question again, carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the drive model will significantly change this question. You need to find a matching PCB BIOS. Let me know the model and I can try to help further.

Please be aware any of the symptoms below and a replacement PCB will most likely not save the drive:

1. The drive will power up normally (no ticking noises, errors etc) but will not be recognized by the computer;
2. The drive will power up normally and be recognized correctly but will report a size of 0 bytes;
3. The drive will power up but report SMART errors on boot;

If the drive doesn't power up or it display inaccurately in the BIOS then its like a PCB replacement will help save the drive.

Comment: The drive is a Samsung SpinPoint H641JI.

Comment: Right so on a samsung the board number is etched on the side of the PCB. It is on the same side as the main controller IC (the biggest chip on the board). It's normally in a format of LLNN-NNNNNL (L for letter, N for number..). The main problem you'll have is the BIOS (ROM or NVRAM chip) if you have an incompatible BIOS chip the PCB will not be able to read the data. They can be updated but it involves physically lifting and replacing the chipset from the board.

Comment: Sorry just looking in to SpinPoint PCB number and I believe they are on the bottom of the PCB near the connections (SATA)

Comment: Yes, I remember a sticker on the PCB just below the SATA connectors- I'll check when I get home.